# Clip off last digits from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have the following array

```
var arr = ['1234','23C','456','356778', '56']
```

I want to remove array elements which are less than 3 characters and greater than 4 characters. The final result should be as follows

```
arr = ['1234', '23C', '456'];  //only 3 and 4 digits in the array.
```

Secondly, I want to do the following. if 'arr' has elements longer than 3 characters, I need to clip of by removing the last digit. The final 'data' array should look like this.

```
arr = ['123', '23C', '456'];
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: alecTMH- i have a different conditon here and i am not able to figure out from that link.

Comment: Are you trying to do two different things to two separate arrays? Or are you trying to filter the array to 3s and 4s, and then change the size of the values with 4 or more?

Comment: KevBot. Yes. Filter array to 3s and 4s from 3s,4s,5s,2s and then change the 4s to all 3s....

Comment: Filter the array with a predicate that checks the number is greater than 99 and less than 10000

Comment: @GruffBunny- i might have alphanumeric in some cases... for e.g. '1234D', 'ER3' etc...

Comment: *I tried searching online and could not find anything related to this.* Well, of course you couldn't. No one else has this problem. But you could find thousands of references about how to filter arrays, or how to transform the items in arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 let isValidElement = updated_ImportDetails.ImportData.filter(function (num) {
                    // is a 3 or 4 digit number
                    return num.length > 2 && num.length <4 ;
                });




                var result = isValidElement.map(function (num) {
                    num = num.substring(0, 3);
                    return num;
                });

                result = result.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
                    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
                })    //removes duplicates from the array
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you can just use `filter` to filter out numbers that aren't composed of 3 digits.

```js
var arr = [1234, 234, 456, 356778, 56];
var result = arr.filter(function(num) {
  return num < 1000 && num >= 100;
});

console.log(result);
```

For the second part, you can use `map`. Just convert the number to a string. If the length of it is greater than 3, take the substring composed of the first 3 elements of the string, then convert back to a number.

```js
var data = [1234, 123, 4567, 3333];
var result = data.map(function(num) {
  num = num.toString().substring(0, 3);
  return parseInt(num);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

All You want is `Array.filter` and `Array.map`, and converting String to Number

```
var arr = [1234,234,456,356778, 56]

var newArr = arr.filter((num) => {
  // convert number to string
  var str = '' + num
  // if length is 3 or 4 - return true (element will be in newArr)
  return str.length === 3 && str.length === 4 
})
```

and the second case

```
var newArr = arr.map((num) => {
  var str = '' + num
  // is str is longer than 3, cut it to length of 3
  if(str.length > 3)
    str = str.substring(0, 3)
  // return str converted to number
  return +str
})
```

Comment: @grzesiekgs- are you sure of the syntax used in array.filter. i am getting errors...

Comment: I've written it from memory. It's ES6 syntax

You can replace 
`(arg) =>` with `function(arg)`

Comment: @grzesiekgs- can you edit your answer so i can accept it as the correct answer please

Comment: Why is the ` if(str.length > 3)` necessary?

Comment: I don't think `str.length === 3 && str.length === 4` is going to work. Did you test this?

Comment: @AduRao It would work. String is like an array, it has 'length', which means how many characters is in string.

The code which You have accepted as an anserw, is ok, but well it's not optimized.

First example is pretty much ok. But I wouldn't use it because You have to hard code minimum and maximum value - which is bad.

In second example, there is toString() and parseInt() methods, which are indeed very verbose, but it's not the fastest way of converting (You can look for some benchmarks).

Also - new string with length of 3 is always created, even if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To handle if a number is 3 or 4 digits, check if each number is in the range 100 <= num < 10000

```
  let result = arr.filter(function(val) {
    // is a 3 or 4 digit number
    return 100 >= val && num < 10000;
  });
```

To clip the four digits to 3 digits, we can divide all four digit numbers by 10 and convert them to an integer

```
  let clippedResult = result.map(function(val) {
    return val >= 1000 ? Math.floor(val / 10) : val
  });
```

Comment: @ megawac- my array elements might contain alphanumeric. :( this will fail in those conditions. right ?

Comment: Modulus does not do what he wants.

Comment: ah my bad, thought it was chopping the start not the end. Fixed that oversight

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterArray(arr,lowDigits,highDigits){
    var newArr=[];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         val=arr[i];
         length=val.length;
         if(length>=lowDigits&&length<=highDigits){
          if(length>lowDigits){
          val=val.substring(0,lowDigits);
          }
          newArr.push(val);
         }
     }
     return newArr;
}

var arr = ['1234','234','456','356778','56'];
arr=filterArray(arr,3,4);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes, because it treats them as strings.

Comment: @sigil- this doesnot work properly. if i do arr = filterArray(arr, 6,7)... i get this result ---> ["004561", "045449", "00456"]. i.e. it shows 5 character value too in the output. '00456'

Comment: @AduRao What was the input array when you tested?  I just ran `["004561", "045449", "00456"]` with `filterArray(arr,6,7)` and got back `["004561", "045449"]` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts the input array to a string of the form `1234,23C,456,356778,56`, then finds the wanted elements using regexp.

```js
var arr = ['1234','23C','456','356778', '56'];

console.log(String(arr).match(/\b\w{3}(?=\w?\b)/g));
```

In English:

> Find all the substrings which start with a word boundary (`\b`, which will be after a comma, or the beginning of the string), then have three alphanumeric characters, and which looking ahead (`(?=`) may (`?`) have one additional character before the next word boundary (comma or end of string).

And yes, this **will** work with string elements, as long as the strings are composed of alphanumerics (in other words, things which won't break the word break (`\b`) logic.